# Nokia Lumia 630 & TV output

Tags: nokia-lumia-630

Can I connect the Nokia Lumia 630 to an old TV using [Nokia CA-75U TV-Out cable (from N95/6)](http://www.all4phone.com/eng_pl_Nokia-Video-Out-Cable-CA-75U-CA75U-TV-Cable-N79-N82-N85-N95-N95-8GB-N96-12_4.jpg)

Answer (score 4):

**No, you can't with that cable.**

Most modern phones don't have a TV-out (or HDMI out). Instead they have wireless options like Airplay on the iPhone, which requires a device to Airplay to such as the Apple TV.

With Windows Phone 8.1, a feature called **[Project My Screen](https://www.windowsphone.com/en-ie/how-to/wp8/connectivity/project-my-phone-screen)** was introduced. Only newer devices support the wireless option, but it possible to mirror your device with a TV or PC.